# Efficient data structure for matching one of a list of regexes

Tags: java, regex, search, data-structures

I have a class MyRegex

```
public class MyRegex {
    private Pattern pattern;
    private Map<String, Object> attributes;
    public MyRegex() {
        this.pattern = null;
        this.attributes = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    }
    public MyRegex(String regex) {
        this.pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
        this.attributes = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    }
    public MyRegex withRegex(String regex) {
        this.pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
        return this;
    }
    public void putAttribute(String attrName, Object attrValue) {
        attributes.put(attrName, attrValue);
    }
    public Map<String, Object> getAttributes() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableMap(attributes);
    }
    public Pattern getPattern() {
        return pattern;
    }
    public Matcher matcher(CharSequence str) {
        return pattern.matcher(str);
    }
}
```

And I have this class:

```
public class MyRegexMeta {
    private String metaFileName;

    private List<MyRegex> attrModelList;

    public MyRegexMeta(String metaFileName) {
        this.metaFileName = metaFileName;
        loadConfig();
        startConfigLoader();
    }

    private void startConfigLoader() {
        new Thread(new ConfigLoader()).start();
        log.info("Config loader started");
    }

    private class ConfigLoader implements Runnable {
        public void run() {
            final int sleepSeconds = 7200;
            // load config periodically, so that the it's up to date.
            while (true) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(sleepSeconds * 1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    log.error("Failed to make loading thread to sleep. ", e);
                    continue;
                }
                loadConfig();
            }
        }
    }

    private void loadConfig() {
        // Read configuration from a file, and store in a list.
    }

    public void generateAttributes(String name, Map<String, Object> attrs) {
        List<MyRegex> tempModelList = attrModelList;
        Map<String, MyRegex> matched = new HashMap<String, MyRegex>();
        for (MyRegex model : tempModelList) {
            Matcher matcher = model.matcher(name);
            if (matcher.matches()) {
                for (String attrName : model.getAttributes().keySet()) {
                    matched.put(attrName, model);
                }
                attrs.putAll(model.getAttributes());
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This code is part of a service that is running. Each line of my text file that I read in `loadConfig` has a regex, and a set of attributes. I call generateAttributes passing in a name, and a Map to hold the attributes that correspond to the regex that matches my name.

I call generateAttributes several times a second, so it's important that it is fast. Also, my names are not evenly distributed. Say I have 200 regex lines in my attrModelList. Perhaps 20 of those lines will match 70% of the names that I pass in. I know that a sequential search for a matching regex will be O(n), but I would like to have the average case better than O(n).

How can I make this code more efficient in the average case?

Comment: I don't see how you're going to do that, considering you seem to need to check all regexes for every line. If you don't, calling `continue` after a match is something you can do away with.

Comment: What you might be describing is fuzzy search, depending on what your REs look like. Can you give some examples of your regular expressions so we can determine if a fuzzy inverted index might be appropriate?

Comment: ".*-co-ct-t[0-9]+.*",  "[a-z]{3}[0-9]+-eu-mig-f[0-9].*", ".*ooq-pok-afs-t[0-9]+.*"